# Convert .bcp to SQL?

Tags: sqlite

I have downloaded a set of data I found online which has the extension .bcp which I have never seen before. How would I go about converting this to XML or .txt to import into SQLite?

EDIT: Solved by importing directly into SQLite3 using tab as delimiter

Comment: What program generates a .bcp file? Maybe contact the vendor and see if they have a solution. Are the contents in any standard data format to begin with? Try opening it in notepad and see. You might even be able to just use it as a text file if the format is OK.

Comment: I found out bcp utility is used to export microsoft SQL server tables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) however there is no mention of a .bcp file. The file is 8GB so I can't open with notepad and crashes when I try to open with atom.

Comment: Forget about notepad. Either get a good viewer or cat / type foo.bcp | more to check the content.

Comment: Suggestion: either answer your own question or delete it

Answer (score 0):

Solved by importing directly into SQLite3 using tab as delimiter.